# DAX to separate number with commas

Tags: dax

I need to separate a number with commas
for example number 142531 to show as 14:25:31

Googled for a while and found something like this:

```
Column =
VAR right =
    RIGHT ( [Column1], 3 )
VAR left =
    SUBSTITUTE ( [Column1], right, "" )
RETURN
    COMBINEVALUES ( ":", left, right )
```

This kinda shows me how to do it, I can separate the number in the middle with 1 comma but not sure how to do this with the middle part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Time = 
VAR left = LEFT ( [RCP_TIME], 2 )
VAR mid = MID ( [RCP_TIME], 3, 2 )
VAR right =  RIGHT ( [RCP_TIME], 2 )
RETURN
COMBINEVALUES(":",left, mid, right)
```

Comment: You should add some text to the answer

Comment: Please add an explanation to the code, to improve the quality and to let the OP better catch the answer.